# How to get all records using Eloquent that aren't associated with a model?

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-8

I'm newbie using the Laravel Framework and I would like to get all countries that's not associate with a group.

Database structure:

```
Schema::create('countries', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->id();
    $table->string('code')->index();
    $table->string('name');
    $table->timestamps();
    $table->softDeletes();
});

Schema::create('groups', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->id();
    $table->string('name');
    $table->foreignId('currency_id')->constrained('currencies')->onDelete('CASCADE')->cascadeOnUpdate();
    $table->timestamps();
});

Schema::create('country_group', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->foreignId('group_id')->constrained('groups')->onDelete('CASCADE')->cascadeOnUpdate();
    $table->foreignId('country_id')->constrained('countries')->onDelete('CASCADE')->cascadeOnUpdate();
});

Schema::create('currencies', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->bigIncrements('id');
    $table->string('name', 50)->unique();
    $table->string('code', 50)->unique();
    $table->string('symbol', 5)->nullable();
    $table->timestamps();
});
```

Group model:

```
class Group extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'groups';
    protected $fillable = ['name','currency_id'];

    public function countries()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Country::class);
    }

    public function currency()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Currency::class);
    }
}
```

Country model:

```
class Country extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'countries';
    protected $fillable = ['code','name'];

    public function provinces()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(CountryProvince::class);
    }
    
    public function group()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Group::class);
    }
}
```

I'm trying to get all the countries that aren't associated with group with:

`Country::doesntHave('group')->get()`

But get the expection:

`` SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'countries.group_id' in 'where clause' (SQL: select * from `countries` where not exists (select * from `groups` where `countries`.`group_id` = `groups`.`id`)) ``

Comment: I think you missed the foreign id in your countries table schema: `$table->foreignId('group_id');`

Comment: I have a pivot (country_group) table for it. I think it enough...

Comment: you have set up a many-to-many relationship. You should create a function in both model and use that for query

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `group` relationship on `Country` also needs to be a `belongsToMany`. If one side is `belongsToMany` the other side must be as well. A `belongsTo` implies the foreign key is on that model, which is not the case as there is a pivot table.